GPU Out of Memory Error during Full-Finetuning of LLAMA-3-8B Model on Multi-GPU Setup
I am writing to seek your expertise and assistance regarding an issue I encountered while attempting to perform full-finetuning of the LLAMA-3-8B model using a Multi-GPU environment with two A100 80GB GPUs.
To test whether full-finetuning is feasible with the available resources, I constructed a simplified training code and executed the following command to use both GPUs in a standalone setup via torchrun.
However, the training process was abruptly halted due to a CUDA out of memory error. This issue persisted even after reducing the batch size from 4 to 1.
Based on my calculations, I believed that full-finetuning should be possible with two A100 80GB GPUs.
Therefore, I am perplexed as to why this configuration fails, even with the batch size set to 1. I would greatly appreciate your opinion on whether there might be an issue with my code, or if full-finetuning under these conditions is inherently unfeasible.
Attached is a screenshot showing the GPU and memory usage just before the CUDA out of memory error occurred.
train.py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, TrainingArguments, BitsAndBytesConfig
from datasets import load_dataset
from trl import SFTTrainer, DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM
import torch 

# gpu device map 
from accelerate import PartialState
from trl import  is_xpu_available

torch.cuda.empty_cache()

device_map = (
                {"": f"xpu:{PartialState().local_process_index}"}
                if is_xpu_available()
                else {"": PartialState().local_process_index}
            )

dataset = load_dataset("lucasmccabe-lmi/CodeAlpaca-20k", split="train")

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("beomi/Llama-3-Open-Ko-8B", device_map = device_map)


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B")
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))  # indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [858,0,0], thread: [95,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.

def formatting_prompts_func(example):
    output_texts = []
    for i in range(len(example['instruction'])):
        text = f"### Question: {example['instruction'][i]}\n ### Answer: {example['output'][i]}"
        output_texts.append(text)
    return output_texts

response_template = " ### Answer:"
collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(response_template, tokenizer=tokenizer)

training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir='./model',
        per_device_train_batch_size=1,
        num_train_epochs = 1,
    )

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    args=training_arguments,
    formatting_func=formatting_prompts_func,
    data_collator=collator,
)

trainer.train()

torchrun command
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 torchrun --standalone --nproc_per_node=2 --master_port=3333 train.py

gpu and memory usage
Screenshot of GPU and memory usage just before the CUDA out of memory error.

please let me know how to perform full-finetuning with two A100 80GB GPUs
